# Crop both sides of a CSS shape when resizing

Tags: html, css

I have this triangle:

[image]

When browser gets smaller it is cropped this way:

[image]

I would like it to crop from both left and right, so the text would still be viewable.

Markup:

```
echo '<div class="triangle"><p class="season">SEASON '.substr($patch_array[$x][0],0,1).'</p></div>';
```

CSS:

```
.season{
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -35px;
    left: -60px;
    position: relative;
    width: 113px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
}
.triangle{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-left: 300px solid transparent;
    border-right: 300px solid transparent;
    border-top: 45px solid #6699ff;
}
```

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/eeueckvb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to set the container to relative position, then draw the shape with pseudo element, and set both the shape and text as absolute position and always stay centered.

Also made a some small improvement - changed left and right border style to `outset`, it does the trick to make lines look much smoother on Firefox.

Try the demo, resize the output frame, and see how the shape and text always stay in the center.

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r89yvfLt/)

```css
.triangle {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.triangle:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 300px outset transparent;
    border-right: 300px outset transparent;
    border-top: 45px solid #6699ff;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
.season {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
    <p class="season">Hello World</p>
</div>
```